# JavaScript edit InnerHTML from a tag by class and id

Tags: javascript, jquery

For these links

```
<div class="post_actions"> 
    <a class="color-transition article_delete" href=""><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
    <a class="color-transition article_edit" href="#" id="1"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
</div>
```

I try to edit their content on click based on each id and class.

Ultil now I have used

```
$('.article_delete').html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />');
```

But every `.article_delete` class from page is changing the InnerHTML content.
I tried this:

```
$('.article_delete#'+article_id).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />');
```

and this (from a stackoverflow similar post):

```
document.getElementById(article_id).getElementsByClassName("article_delete")[0].html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />');
```

Any solution? I want to select only `.article_delete` where `id="something"`.

Comment: `and this (from a stackoverflow similar post)` - name and shame that post - trying to use a jQuery function in vanilla JS should be punishable!

Comment: the element with class article_delete doesn't have an ID, so you'll be hard pressed using an ID

Comment: The code does not have any problem. See https://jsfiddle.net/4kctstoq/

Comment: try using `.text()`, The code already work anyway

Comment: @Mohammad - the html in your fiddle is quite different to that in the question

Comment: @JaromandaX I said `$(".class#id")` selector is right but in question code there is no any element contain `.article_delete` and id.

Comment: I said your **HTML** differs, didn't say you were wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX I know.

Comment: @Mohammad - I misunderstood your comment. I thought when you said `The code does not have any problem` that you meant the code in the **question** has no problem ... you meant "the code" in you fiddle

Comment: @Mohammad, i forgot to put the di for the first link. As Drone answered bellow, i can't use unique ids at all. I have unique ids for each article, but each article has it's own lniks, each of these with it's specific article id. My problem is: when i click on delete, the InnerHTML changes for .delete_article and for .like (another class) and this is not what i intended to do. Or if i select by class, every class from page (eg. .article_delete) changes it's content.

Comment: How are you handling the clicks? Update your question with code and selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution myself.
Because i needed the ids from each div to parse them with ajax to php i added just another class for each link.
Here is an example:

PHP

```
 <a class="color-transition  article_spam_flag asf'.$id.'" href="#" id="'.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a>
```

JS

```js
$(function() {
$(".article_spam_flag").click(function() {
var article_id = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'article_id='+article_id;  
//$('a#'+article_id).removeClass('liked');
//document.getElementById(article_id).getElementsByClassName("article_spam_flag")[0].html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />');
//$('.article_spam_flag#'+article_id).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
  //$(this).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
  $('.asf'+article_id).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "action/article_spam_flag.php",
 data: dataString,
 cache: false,
 success: function(data){
    if (data == 0) {
 alert('Actiunea nu a putut fi realizata!');
 } else {
 //$('.article_spam_flag').fadeIn("slow").html(data);
 $('.asf'+article_id).fadeIn("slow").html(data);
 //$(this).fadeIn("slow").html(data);
 //window.location.href="contact.php?categorie=ArticolFlag: "+article_id;
 //floating contact
 }
 }  
});
return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="post_actions"> 
<a class="color-transition article_delete" href="" id="test-2"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
<a class="color-transition article_edit" href="#" id="test-1"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
</div>
```

Now take a look at js:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".post_actions").on("click","[id^=test]",function(){
  $(this).html("your new html");
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get element by **ID** you must use the Prefix `#`:

```
$('#' + ELEM_ID )
```

To get element by **CLASS** you must use the Prefix `.`:

```
$('.' + ELEM_ID )
```

To get element by **TAG** you must use enter the tag name without any prefix:

```
$('div')
```

There are many type of selectors and you can combine selectors to get specific result

[jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

In your example you can use the `this` to access clicked element and change it.

#### Example:

```js
$('.article').on("click", function(){
  $(this).html('<span>LOADING ... </span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    
    <div class="post_actions"> 
      <a class="color-transition article" href="#">ACTION 1</a>
      <br>
      <a class="color-transition article" href="#">ACTION 2</a>
      <br>
      <a class="color-transition article" href="#">ACTION 3</a>
      <br>
      <a class="color-transition article" href="#">ACTION 4</a>
      <br>
      <a class="color-transition article" href="#">ACTION 5</a>
      <br>
      <a class="color-transition article" href="#">ACTION 6</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Id, something like this,

```
 <div class="post_actions"> 
 <a class="color-transition article_delete adding-img" id="unique_id1" href=""><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
 <a class="color-transition article_edit adding-img" href="#" id="unique_id2"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
    </div>
```

and in js for any one say for id `unique_id1`

```
$('#unique_id1').html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />');
```

for both

```
$('#unique_id1,#unique_id2').html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />');
```

By using class, only that class where you want this

$('.adding-img').html('');

Comment: i can't use unique ids like that because i need them to be sent to a php file. The problem is i have a bunch of articles, each of the with these link wich have the article`s id.